# Why does rtx 4090 has more tensor cores than h100

Tags: graphics-cards

The `rtx 4090` has 512 tensor cores and the `h100` has 456 tensor cores. I thought that tensor cores were much more important for AI and ML workloads.

Why does the `rtx 4090` have more tensor cores than the `h100`? `h100` being a data center gpu? I would expect it to have more tensor cores than the `rtx 4090`. Can someone explain this to me?